# Passing values with two forms

Tags: c#, forms

the code below is Form1, and when I use it in Form2 it receives en empty string.
Is there a way to pass data between 2 forms ??

```
    public string returnAccount()
    {
        return currentAccount;
    }

    public string returnPassword()
    {
        return currentPassword;
    }

    public string returnIP()
    {
        return currentIP;
    }

    public string returnPort()
    {
        return currentPort;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the instance of the Form you are hoping to gather the data from, you are not creating a new instance are you? What does the retrieval look like?

Comment: How are you calling these methods from your `Form2`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working you're probably using the wrong reference of the forms (if you're writing `new Form1()` in more than one place then that's probably a sign off this).

Something like this should work:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
if(frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string account = frm.returnAccount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `current_` variables need to be assigned values before `Form2` can access them. Are you assigning those variables values in the constructor method of the class of `Form1`?